# tkdiff how to ignore line endings

Tags: tk-toolkit

Using tkdiff on unix platform, I've tried modifying whitespace option in the preferences window to be `-w` or `-b`, neither of which seem to ignore carriage return differences (unix/pc.)

`-w` works with diff from the command line.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, google search landed me here, and answer didn't help me. tkdiff uses diff internally for diffing, so spent few minutes trying all options including --strip-trailing-cr which doesn't help.

Here is options that works - 
use `-B` along with `-w` to make tkdiff ignore all white spaces including blank lines.

`tkdiff -w -B`

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU diff, you can use the `--strip-trailing-cr` option.  I don't know how to tell tkdiff to use that option.